# View created from XML data - Statistics

Tags: sql-server-2012, xml

I am looking at a legacy system that stores XML blobs

A view is created over this so the data is more accessible (for reporting)

```
CREATE view [dbo].[Data]
as
select top 100 percent
data.value('(/Input/@FirstName)[1]','varchar(100)') as FirstName,
(select data.query('for $i in /Input/Control[@Name="Postcode"]/* order by $i/@UpdateDateTime descending return $i')).value('(/Value/@ValueCode)[1]','varchar(50)') as 'Postcode'
...
...
from data
```

Will SQL server generate statistics for queries run against this view?

Comment: I don't know but I do know that that `top 100 percent` is absolutely useless - why is it there?

Comment: Very good question. I am not sure. This is not the way I would have written it. (And I cannot re-write ~ read-only access)

Comment: [TOP 100 Percent ORDER BY Considered Harmful.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/queryoptteam/archive/2006/03/24/560396.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the query optimizer [will not create statistics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177623.aspx) for a view unless it's an indexed view, you can create an [XML index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522451.aspx) on the xml column itself to speed up the view,